# Yahoo! BOSS: Include duplicate results

Tags: search, duplicates, yahoo-boss-api

I can easily get the results I want from Yahoo! BOSS. However, for the particular data I'm trying to get, it's important that "duplicate" results be included. I know Yahoo! has them, since when I search for the query manually, it offers me a link to see these similar results.

Is there any way to request these deeper results with the Yahoo! BOSS API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, it would seem that the answer is, at present, no.

I will continue to pursue the subject [here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/ysearchboss/message/2533).